# View did not return a HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django, authentication

```
def login_view(request):
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        user_name=request.POST['username']
        _password=request.POST['password']
        user=authenticate(request,username=user_name,password=_password)
        if user is not None:
           login(request,user)
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
           return render(request,'users/login.html',{'message':'Invalid Credentials'}) 
  else:
      return render(request,'users/login.html')
```

here is my login.html

```
{% extends "users/layout.html" %}
{% block contents %}

{% if message %}

<div>{{message}}</div>
{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" placeholder="UserName" name="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="login">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I am getting the following error message if i remove last else: when i go to users/ url

```
The view users.views.login_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

if i add last else:  i get TemplateDoesNotExist exception

Here is my project screenshot

[image]

Comment: I just guess that `if request.method=='POST'` evaluates to false, so this function by default returns None

Comment: What if you make a GET request, then the function will not return anything hence `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
def login_view(request):
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        user_name=request.POST['username']
        _password=request.POST['password']
        user=authenticate(request,username=user_name,password=_password)
        if user is not None:
           login(request,user)
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
           return render(request,'users/login.html',{'message':'Invalid Credentials'}) 
    else: # add this
        return render(request,'users/login.html')
```

Since everytime you first acces a view you send a `GET` method your view throws an error since it has nothing defined for it, when you add `else` you essentially saying if `request.method` is anything else but `POST` then render the template. Then when you are on the page you can send a `POST` request and your view will handle it like it should

Comment: Please explain what your code does differently and how it does it.

Comment: I tried this above suggested already it throws exception due to last line that you added

Comment: whats the exception?

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist

Comment: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: users/login.html.

Comment: I have login.html in templates

Comment: can you add the template to the question?

Comment: thanks i edited it and fully reposted with both situations

Comment: try to create a seperate view that just renders your `login.html`, you probably just specified a wrong path for it, can you also maybe add a screenshot of your project structure showing all apps with folders (especially the one with `login.html`) and also add your settings `TEMPLATES` dictionary to the question

Comment: thanks now full project structure is available

Comment: add settings `TEMPLATES` to the question as well please

Comment: Does not works but there is no need of specifying templates but i tried it don't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226308/discussion-between-sldem-and-janson).